# Any way to check OS compatibility on iPhone/iPad devices in official Apple website?

Tags: ios, ipad

Because of some reason, I have to prove iOS 6 couldnt be installed in iPad 1st generation... to someone who dose not believe even Wikipedia.

I know this is somewhat wired, but is there any official apple webpage that describing OS compatibility for each apple devices ?

Thanks

Comment: Scroll Down To Apple Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422447/what-iphone-devices-will-run-on-armv7s-and-arm64/21422550#21422550

Comment: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1578?locale=en_US Check "System Requirements"

Comment: CRDave 25: Thank you so much. Is there any official 'list' of devices as well ? If there is any list for this, it will be helpful later project. Anyway, Thanks again : )

Comment: Refer my first comment. That answer has many links to check a different kind of device compatibility.